# python recursion with bubble sort

Tags: python, recursion, bubble-sort

So, i have this problem where i recieve 2 strings of letters ACGT, one with only letters, the other contain letters and dashes "-".both are same length. the string with the dashes is compared to the string without it. cell for cell. and for each pairing i have a scoring system. i wrote this code for the scoring system:
for example:
dna1: -ACA
dna2: TACG
the scoring is -1. (because dash compared to a letter(T) gives -2, letter compared to same letter gives +1 (A to A), +1 (C to C) and non similar letters give (-1) so sum is -1.

```
def get_score(dna1, dna2, match=1, mismatch=-1, gap=-2):
""""""

score = 0

for index in range(len(dna1)):
    if dna1[index] is dna2[index]:
        score += match
    elif dna1[index] is not dna2[index]:
        if "-" not in (dna1[index], dna2[index]):
            score += mismatch
        else:
            score += gap
```

this is working fine.

now i have to use recursion to give the best possible score for 2 strings.
i recieve 2 strings, they can be of different sizes this time. ( i cant change the order of letters).
so i wrote this code that adds "-" as many times needed to the shorter string to create 2 strings of same length and put them in the start of list. now i want to start moving the dashes and record the score for every dash position, and finally get the highest posibble score. so for moving the dashes around i wrote a litle bubble sort.. but it dosnt seem to do what i want. i realize its a long quesiton but i'd love some help. let me know if anything i wrote is not understood.

```
def best_score(dna1, dna2, match=1, mismatch=-1, gap=-2,\
                         score=[], count=0):
""""""

diff = abs(len(dna1) - len(dna2))

if len(dna1) is len(dna2):
    short = []
elif len(dna1) < len(dna2):
    short = [base for base in iter(dna1)]
else:
    short = [base for base in iter(dna2)]

for i in range(diff):
    short.insert(count, "-")

for i in range(diff+count, len(short)-1):
    if len(dna1) < len(dna2):
        score.append((get_score(short, dna2),\
                      ''.join(short), dna2))
    else:
        score.append((get_score(dna1, short),\
                      dna1, ''.join(short)))
    short[i+1], short[i] = short[i], short[i+1]

if count is min(len(dna1), len(dna2)):
    return score[score.index(max(score))]
return best_score(dna1, dna2, 1, -1, -2, score, count+1)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it looks like you are trying to find the best possible place (defined as the highest score) to insert the sequence of dashes into the shorter DNA string, where all of the dashes are adjacent?

Comment: the dashes are inserted by me incase 1 string is shorter than the other. so basically you are right, i need to find the optimal place for the dashes to get the highest score. i figure that if i place them in the start i could move the rightmost dash each step untill the end via bubble sort, and then reset the dashes and move them 1 cell forward and repeast the process. that way i record all possible scores and return the highest. incase the strings are same size i dont have to insert dashes. that case solves with the first function because there is only 1 possible score for it.. nothing moves.

Comment: for example: TCAATTAGCTT', 'TATA'  are the 2 strings. i insert the dashes to right untill its same length and then move them around inside the right string for optimal score according to rules. i cant change the order of letters.

Comment: can you split your smaller string with dashes? i.e. `T-A-T-A----`

Comment: yea, as long as the total length is equal to the other string and as long as i dont change order of letter. i can do whatever i want with the dashes to produce the highest score

Comment: also i dont care about run time.. it realize this can take like 10 minutes for large strings

Answer (score 0):

First, if I correctly deciephered your cost function, your best score value do not depend on gap, as number of dashes is fixed.

Second, it is lineary dependent on number of mismatches and so doesn't depend on match and mismatch exact values, as long as they are positive and negative respectively.

So your task reduces to lookup of a longest subsequence of longest string letters strictly matching subsequence of letters of the shortest one.

Third, define by `M(string, substr)` function returnin length of best match from above. If you smallest string fisrt letter is `S`, that is `substr == 'S<letters>'`, then

```
M(string, 'S<letters>') = \
    max(1 + M(string[string.index(S):], '<letters>') + # found S
            M(string[1:], '<letters>')) # letter S not found, placed at 1st place
```

latter is an easy to implement recursive expression.

For a pair `string, substr` denoting `m=M(string, substr)` best score is equal

```
m * match + (len(substr) - m) * mismatch + (len(string)-len(substr)) * gap
```

It is straightforward, storing what value was max in recursive expression, to find what exactly best match is.

Comment: alko ill give u an example from school solution: dna1: TAGCAAG
dna2: TGGGCAAATTGAACCGGAAT.  >>>>>>>
(-21, 'T------A--G---C--AAG', 'TGGGCAAATTGAACCGGAAT')
 is the output tuple containing answer. as you can see score is at the start of tuple, then they added dashes to make strings even and for maximum score of -21 it is found that the dashes should be in that exact order.

Comment: @user2970357 you give it what for? this case complies with what is written in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code entirely. What if, for example, dna1 is TAGAGACAGC, and dna2 is AGCGACGCGAAGCGAGCGACCGAT. If I'm reading this correctly, it'll look for "T", find it at the very end, and then the rest of the letters will have to be placed after?

Comment: @user2970357 that try is first expression in `max(...)`; second denotes case when T is placed at first place and 'A' is looked for starting from second.

Comment: alko this looks right but i cant understand the code. wondering if it could be written in a more user friendly way for a python beginner like myself